# How to resize jpg files in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm studying photo upload script.
Here is my code below this works fine.

I would like to add resizing photo function.

I would like to Keep same RATIO (height and width) And

I would like to change it around 2.8M (1920 x 1440) size
or make it all photo will be max width size is 1920.

Could you teach me how to add this fucntion to my code please?

UPDATE(I add Dear Dilip Hirapara code )

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ImageGallery;
use DB;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

 public function upload(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg|max:90480'
    ]);

    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);


    if($request->hasFile('image')) {

$image       = $request->file('image');
$filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

$image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
$image_resize->resize(300, 300);
$image_resize->save(public_path('images/ServiceImages/' .$filename));

}
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);

ImageGallery::create($input);

    return back()
        ->with('sucess','sucess');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `intervention/image` by using this command.

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Check the [official document](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) for installation

check this link to [resize](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize) image.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {

    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
    $image_resize->save(public_path('images/ServiceImages/' .$filename));

}
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for code. I really apreciate. May I ask one things? I have this error Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Unable to find file (/var/tmp/phpvnQjg0 . I searched at web... Is it temp file problem?

Comment: The problem is when you upload any file first it goes to tmp folder..once that file moved or if we use move action the tmp file automatically deleted. that's why right now you're unable to find it.

Comment: Add your move functionality after this code. `$file->move($path, $filename);`

Comment: Dear @Dilip Hirapara Now I understand the temp meaning Thank you very much again. Well actually I add your code but I still got same error. I update my current code. Could you take a look it? And Could you teach me what is cause  my writing?

Comment: The move function should be in last..check my edited answer.  `$file->move($path, $filename);` remove this line..and add your move function.

Comment: Dear @Dilip Hirapara Thank you for helping me. I got still same error. I update my code again. Could you take a look it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214727/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-greeniron).

Comment: remove this highlighted line because you've added it down. check edited answer. you shouldn't use move function before the resize or save?

Comment: Dear @Dilip Hirapara Thank you. Yes I'm in chat now.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was amazing lesson!